# Angular HttpClient Post request Firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, post, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to make my Web Application available for at least Chrome and Firefox.
But if i make a post request, i am getting this Error with Firefox:

```
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
```

I already set the CORS request header in my Rest API (Spring Boot Application) to 
    http://localhost:4200
and everything is working fine in Chrome. It just fails wit Firefox and Internet Explorer.

The Method who performs the Post Request:

```
    public saveProject(patchBuildName: string, project: IProject){
        this._http.post(this._baseUrl+'insertProject?patchBuildName='+patchBuildName+"&year="+this.year,project,httpOptions)
       .subscribe();
     }
```

The httpOptions:

> 'content-type':  'application/json'

I would be very grateful for your help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the HTTP code?

Comment: all i can see is this `message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"`

Comment: may be this is unrelated by why are you subscribing in the post method itself,, it should be in the component.

Comment: Hi Niladri. This is the whole error

Comment: ERROR 
{…}
​
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map }
​
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: null
​
__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse() }

Comment: If you check in the browsers "network" tab of the developer tools, can you please let us know what Url it is sending to, and what response it receives?

Comment: Are you using a POST and put the parameters in a Query?

Comment: @user184994 i have no entry in this list. It is like it is never called from Firefox.

Comment: @Eliseo Yes i am parsing the POST Object in the API and i save this Object in a Database

Answer (score 0):

I think you are framing the wrong url in post request

this._baseUrl+'insertProjectpatchBuildName='+patchBuildName+"&year="+this.year

here the query string separator ? is missing in the url i think.

Comment: Actually, this was just an error in my question. I happened while i was formatting, sorry.